# How TO - Quotes Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Wondering If someone could help me, I'm relatively new to Javascript. I'm trying to use the QUOTES Slideshow code using the link below, however, i can't seem to solve the issue and Javascript shows the following errors:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_quotes_slideshow.asp

- ERROR 'plusSlides' is defined but never used. {no-unused-vars}
- ERROR 'currentSlides' is defined but never used. {no-unused-vars}

For some reason, when you copy and paste all the code to a html doc it seems to work but when I try to separate the code into their respective locations It doesn't seem to work showing the errors above.

Code shown below, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could assist me / or even point me in the right direction to better code. Ideally I wouldn't mind having 3 div tags (Inc 3 quotes) per slideshow because this code only give me one quote per slideshow.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
q {font-style: italic;}

/* Add a blue color to the author */
.author {color: cornflowerblue;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="Untitled-2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="untitled-3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
  <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
  <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
  <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting these errors? The code works well.

Comment: On the following lines under Javascript tab: 
function plusSlides(n), {function currentSlide(n) {

Comment: Ok, so I got it working a little, but I still have an issue. For some reason, when I load the code onto chrome, I can't see the quotes to start off with and I have to click the 3 dots in order for the quotes to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can make these changes to obtain the right results
You have not specify width and height to slideshow-container ,also I see a slidesShow function not working properly until full Dom loads,so I applied a load() to body that's why code is not working properly
***HTML&css***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    /

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      margin: 0
    }

    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      background: #f1f1f1f1;
    }

    /* Slides */
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
      
      padding: 80px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: -30px;
      padding: 16px;
      color: #888;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      color: white;
    }

    /* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
    .dot-container {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #ddd;
    }

    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

    /* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
    .active, .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }

    /* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
    q {
      font-style: italic;
    }

    /* Add a blue color to the author */
    .author {
      color: cornflowerblue;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Prb4.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="Load()">

  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
      <p class="author">
        - John Keats
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
      <p class="author">
        - Ernest Hemingway
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class="author">
        - Thomas A. Edison
      </p>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  </div>

  <div class="dot-container">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Js***

```
var slideIndex = 1;
function Load(){
showSlides(slideIndex);
}
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  console.log(slides[slideIndex-1])
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```